# springboot download file, the bowser is loaded all at once into memory

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

In springboot,backend is cyclically written to the response outputstream,but the bowser is loaded all at once into memory and then written to the hard drive，why is exist this thing?

my code as follow:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if (!file.exists()) {
    return ResponseDTO.wrap(FileResponseCodeConst.FILE_NOT_EXIST);
}
response.reset();
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(fileName + filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".")), "UTF-8"));

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setBufferSize(64*1024);
try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))
{
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    int i=0;
    while ((i = bis.read(buff)) != -1) {
        os.write(buff, 0, i);
        os.flush();
    }
    bis.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("{}", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    return ResponseDTO.wrap(FileResponseCodeConst.FILE_DOWNLOAD_ERROR);
}

return ResponseDTO.succMsg(FileResponseCodeConst.FILE_DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS);
```

```
export const getDownloadAxios = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
};
```

fix this bug,i did not find this problem

Comment: Why are you downloading using axios? Can't you just put a link to the file on the page? Then you don't need to handle any logic in JS and the browser does all the work for you.

Comment: thx, i found that it not use js ,patse this link into URL bar is work normal.